# How to add string if two arrays are in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array values if there are two values i need to add a string "AND" if single value "AND" string should not be added. i have tried with the following code. cant get the required output

```
$unserialize_meta = array(0=>"Alcor",1=>"President",2=>"Treasurer");
$checks = array();
foreach($unserialize_meta as $meta){
    $checks[]= $meta;
}

echo implode(" And ",$checks);

Output:

Alcor And President
Alcor And President And

required output:
Alcor And President
Alcor And President
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace the loop with `$checks = array_values($unserialize_meta);`

Comment: Why isn't `Treasurer` in your expected output?

Comment: Treasurer was not checked actualy these are checked checkboxes values

Comment: Now I see you're already using `implode()`. You shouldn't be getting an extra `AND` unless there's an empty value in the array.,

Comment: You also shouldn't get two lines of output, you just have a single `echo`. There must be more that you're not showing us.

Comment: `Alcor And President And` means there are 3 values and last one is empty string/null

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implode function for this. Details can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Considering the above code:

```
$unserialize_meta = array(0=>"Alcor",1=>"President",2=>"Treasurer");
$checks = implode(" AND ", array_filter($unserialize_meta));
var_dump($checks);
```

The `array_filter` will remove any empty values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake saved in array values in array I'm getting empty array. So I add a empty array check :

```
if(!empty($meta)){
    $checks[]= $meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you don't need to loop array. you just need to `implode` array with the string. Please try below code it will add string `AND` with your array values.

```
$unserialize_meta = array(0=>"Alcor",1=>"President",2=>"Treasurer");
if(!empty($unserialize_meta )) {
    echo implode(" And ",$unserialize_meta);
}
```

Output:

`Alcor And President And Treasurer`